# Как правильно в Nginx спроксировать на другой порт WebSocket's?

Tags: javascript, nginx, http, websocket

На сервере есть приложение, слушает порт 7777 и ждет подключение по ws://

Коротко о том как должно работать: 
Браузер -> Nginx(HTTPS) -> WS Сервер (тут мы хотим не использовать сертификат, из-за чего и такие заморочки)

Проблема в том, что по какой-то причине при отправлении данных на сервер приходит только часть сообщений из JS:

[image: Отправка данных в хроме]
[image: Что получаем на сервере]

Всегда приходит 1 буква от сообщения, что очень странно.
Попробовал запустить все то же на локальной Windows машине, все работает как надо.

Запускал на c# с помощью [websocket-sharp](https://github.com/sta/websocket-sharp)

```
WebSocketServer srv = new WebSocketServer(7777);
srv.AddWebSocketService<MyClient>("/ws");//сюда должен перенаправлять proxy_pass
srv.Start();
Console.WriteLine("Server is listening......");

//простой listener с выводом данных
class MyClient : WebSocketBehavior
{

    protected override void OnOpen() {  Write("Client Connected!", ConsoleColor.Green); }
    protected override void OnClose(CloseEventArgs e) {  Write("Close connection: "+ e.Reason, ConsoleColor.Red); }
    protected override void OnError(ErrorEventArgs e) { Write("Error: "+e.Message, ConsoleColor.DarkRed, ConsoleColor.Gray);  }
    protected override void OnMessage(MessageEventArgs e) { Write(e.Data); }
 }
```

Простой JS клиент:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("wss://мой-сайт/Game");
socket.onopen = function() {
   console.log("Соединение установлено.");
            activeBtns(false);
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
  if (event.wasClean) {
   console.log('Соединение закрыто чисто');
  } else {
   console.log('Обрыв соединения'); // например, "убит" процесс сервера
  }
   console.log('Код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason);
  activeBtns(true);
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
   console.log("Получены данные ");
   console.log(event.data);
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
   console.log("Ошибка " + error.message);
  activeBtns(true);
};
activeBtns();
sendData = function(){
  socket.send("test message");
};
```

На сервере(OS: Ubuntu) есть Nginx с настройками(устанавливал чистый v1.14.1):

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
  worker_connections 768;
  # multi_accept on;
}

http {
  sendfile on;
  keepalive_timeout 604800;
  proxy_connect_timeout 604800;
  proxy_send_timeout 604800;
  proxy_read_timeout 604800;

  include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;

  access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

  include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
  include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}

#конфиг моего домена:
server {
  listen       443 ssl;
  server_name  мой-сайт; #тут мой домен

  access_log /etc/nginx/logs/log.access;
  error_log /etc/nginx/logs/log.error error;

  ssl on;
  ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/cert.pem;
  ssl_certificate_key /etc/ssl/private/cert.key;

  client_max_body_size 1M;
  client_body_buffer_size 1M;

  location / {
      root /var/www/мой-сайт/html;
      index  index.html index.htm;
  }

  location /Game {
    proxy_pass  http://мой-сайт:7777/ws;
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

  }
}
```

Возможно, есть еще какие-то настройки которые можно изменить?

Answer (score 0):

Проблема в сервере. Поставил node.js сервак и все заработало